# Проблема с использованием TcpClient

Tags: c#

Всем привет. Недавно начал осваивать C#. Пытаюсь написать простой POP3 клиент, чтобы зайти на почту и забрать письма. Пишу, так сказать, класс для работы с POP сервером.

```
class POP3
{
    TcpClient client;
    public POP3(string host, int port)
    {
       client = new TcpClient(host, port);
    }

    public string Login(string login, string password)
    {
       //return client.Connected.ToString();
        string result = this.SendData("USER or_die");
        result += this.SendData("PASS passsss");
        result += this.SendData("STAT");
        return result;
    }

    private string SendData(string arg)
    {
        Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(arg);
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        //Stream stream = client.GetStream();
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

        data = new Byte[256];
        String responseData = String.Empty;
        Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
        stream.Close();
        return responseData;
    }
}
```

При запуски программы, появляется ошибка

> Операция не разрешается на неподключенных сокетах.

И указывает на строку

> NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

В методе SendData.

А если вынести всё в один метод

```
    public string test()
    {
        client = new TcpClient("pop.bk.ru", 110);
        Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("user or_die");
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        //Stream stream = client.GetStream();
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

        data = new Byte[256];
        String responseData = String.Empty;
        Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
        stream.Close();
        return responseData;
    }
```

То всё работает нормально.

Помогите разобраться :)

Comment: Что-то не то вы делаете с полученным классом.. не иначе. А может, ошибка какая вылезает, а вы проглатываете её. К тому же, вы неправильно выполняете чтение ответа от сервера. При таком подходе у вас не получится сделать надёжный клиент. Что, например, будет, если ответ сервера будет длиннее, чем 256 байт? Или ответ будет нормальным, но из-за какой-нибудь фрагментации вам вернут какую-то часть?

Comment: private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            POP3 pop3 = new POP3("pop.bk.ru", 110);
            //string result = pop3.Login("or_die","Pass");
           // textBox3.Text = result;
          //  textBox3.AppendText(pop3.test());
        }
Да мне пока ловить ответ от сервера в приделах 20 символах всё ровно :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А вы читали документацию? Прочтите, что делает конструктор [TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/115ytk56.aspx):

> Этот конструктор создает новый объект TcpClient и выполняет попытку **асинхронного** подключения к узлу с указанным именем и номером порта.

Просто иногда получается, что сокет успевает открыться к моменту вызова GetStream, а иногда ещё нет.

Используйте метод [Connect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.connect.aspx) вместо конструктора с параметрами перед тем, как вызвать [GetStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream.aspx). И не выполняйте сетевые операции в потоке UI НИКОГДА.

Вообще, выполнение сетевых операций или запуск каких-либо потоков в любых конструкторах - это явный FAIL. В данном случае, очевидный epic fail разработчиков API в .NET.

Comment: Не всегда. Если поток должен обрабатывать что-то в течение жизни объекта, то вполне уместно создавать его в конструкторе, а прибивать в Dispose. Выполнение сетевых операций может быть в конструкторе объекта, если это по семантике требуется для его создания (правда, чаще в таких случаях используют Dependency Injection).

В случае TcpClient это действительно непрозрачно.